# How to UPDATE a table with available values from a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

**Overview**

I'm trying to solve an 'assignment' problem using a stored procedure on the SQL server, rather than by using VBA code in our Access application. The problem is similar to assigning available flight seats to tickets as shown in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d82a/1)

**Tables**

Flight

```
+----------+--------------+
| FlightID | FlightNumber |
+----------+--------------+
|        1 | L1044        |
|        2 | T553         |
|        3 | AC1105       |
+----------+--------------+
```

Seat (filtered for FlightID 2)

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| SeatID | FlightID | SeatNumber |
+--------+----------+------------+
|    104 |        2 | F21        |
|    105 |        2 | A22        |
|    106 |        2 | B33        |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

Ticket (filtered for FlightNumber T553)

```
+----------+--------------+--------+
| TicketID | FlightNumber | SeatID |
+----------+--------------+--------+
|     5003 | T553         | (null) |
|     5005 | T553         | (null) |
|     5006 | T553         | (null) |
|     5007 | T553         | (null) |
+----------+--------------+--------+
```

**Problem**

Given a specific `FlightNumber`, how can I update the `Ticket` table to fill the `SeatID` with available values from the `Seat` table, keeping in mind that each seat ID must be used only once. Additionally, I would like to be able to do this in a transaction if possible.

Expected result:

```
+----------+--------------+--------+
| TicketID | FlightNumber | SeatID |
+----------+--------------+--------+
|     5003 | T553         | 104    |
|     5005 | T553         | 105    |
|     5006 | T553         | 106    |
|     5007 | T553         | (null) |
+----------+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: Is there any particular order to the assignments?

Comment: There is no required order, however, if it's possible to sort the available seats by some arbitrary column I would consider doing that down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign row-numbers to each ticket and each seat in derived tables, join on the row-numbers, then copy over the `SeatID`. The row-numbering ensures only one seat gets assigned to one ticket.

I suggest you pick a suitable ordering column for each table.

```sql
UPDATE t
SET SeatID = s.SeatID 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.FlightNumber ORDER BY t.TicketID)
    FROM Ticket t
    WHERE t.FlightNumber = 'T553'
) t
JOIN Flight f ON f.FlightNumber = t.FlightNumber
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.FlightID ORDER BY s.SeatID)
    FROM Seat s
) s ON s.FlightID = f.FlightID AND s.rn = t.rn;
```

Comment: Is there a way to update all flights at once? Simply removing the WHERE clause would assign seats from incorrect flights. Or should this be posted as a separate question?

Comment: I don't think it would assign seats incorrectly if you remove `WHERE`, the row-numbers are partitioned by `FlightNumber`. It would only fail if `FlightNumber` is not unique. And if they are not unique then it can't be done, you need some way of uniquely matching up `Ticket` with `Flight`

Comment: You're absolutely right... it works exactly as it should. I made the mistake of testing in my head instead of in SQL Fiddle :-)